# Use Azure Application Insights with Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

The Azure documentation covers many examples of integrating Azure Application Insights into different applications types, such as ASP.NET, Java, etc. However, the documentation doesn't show any examples of integrating Application Insights into a Azure WebJob.

Does anyone have link to an example or article that covers how to integrate Azure Application Insights into an Azure WebJob that's built as a Console App?

Comment: As far as official docs go, this is the closest they currently have: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-windows-desktop.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have written a console application that tracks events and metrics via Application Insights, and I figure a WebJob won't be all that different, by adding the following NuGet packages:

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener (this may not be required)

My `ApplicationInsights.config` looks like this:

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
    <TelemetryModules>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
    </TelemetryModules>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

And the simple program does this:

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "the_key";
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = true;

var tc = new TelemetryClient();
tc.TrackRequest("Track Some Request", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3), "200", true);
tc.TrackMetric("XYZ Metric", 100);
tc.TrackEvent("Tracked Event");

tc.Flush(); //need to do this, otherwise if the app exits the telemetry data won't be sent
```

There is also this: [Application Insights on Windows Desktop apps, services and worker roles](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/)

Comment: I just implemented this in a WebJob and didn't need the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener` package or an `ApplicationInsights.config` file.

Comment: It's generally better to use `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer` to get some more default collectors.

Comment: @Brendan, where to write the initialization code of application insights in azure web Job like program.cs or functions.cs. can you please tell me what is recommended approach to write the initialization code of AI.

Comment: Can you update the answer and elborate a bit more on what framework you're using? Currently it's hard to know. Are you running .NET Framework or .NET Core? Also - what is `ApplicationInsights.config` ?

Answer (score 17):

Since the above answer is 2 years old and many things have changed since then. Now there is nuget package available for Application insights integration with Azure Webjobs. You need to install below packages:

1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights (Currently in beta)
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
3. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

Configure JobHostConfiguration as below:

```
string instrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
{
      // build up a LoggerFactory with ApplicationInsights and a Console Logger
       config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, null).AddConsole();
       config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Off;
}
```

See full post on this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration)

Comment: I'm having some getting these instructions to work (project won't build and can't find the concrete LoggerFactory class). It definitely could be something in my project but it seemed like these instructions were for a .NET Core webjob. It wasn't clear if the steps also worked for a non-Core project. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @AaronKrone Make sure you have the 3 nuget package smentioned. This should work for non .net core projects also

Comment: one thing to note that `Microsoft.Extensions.X` packages won't have the AddConsole() method in `v5.X.X`... I've reverted to `v1.1.1` and all works as expected. thanks for the answer Unnie.