# add new custom metrics like "Memory Usage" in Azure webjob's Appinsights

Tags: azure, memory, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

We have a webapp(api) and webjob hosted in Azure. Appinsights were enabled to check the diagnostics. We need to get metrics for the webjob to know the Memory usage.

We tried everything given in this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-performance-counters

But, we are not able to get the metrics in Azure app insights. From another link, we saw in a VM, need to install sdk/counters. Since we are hosting in web app, unable to do this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

-------Edited
Just to clarify the question once more. AppInsights currently shows Available memory, which is metrics showing how much memory left in the server and not pertaining to the app in usage. Is there a way we can add that statistics as a custom feature? Above link gives addition of this metrics to a VM.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469014/use-azure-application-insights-with-azure-webjob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you not seeing Process Private Bytes (I think this is what you were looking for)? Try the following query in Analytics. Or you can change the default selection in UI as well - depending on how/where you view the counters.

```
performanceCounters
| where timestamp >= datetime(2018-08-07T18:00:00.000Z) and timestamp < datetime(2018-08-14T18:00:00.000Z)
| where ((category == "Process" and counter == "Private Bytes") or name == "processPrivateBytes")
| extend performanceCounter_value = iif(itemType == 'performanceCounter',value,todouble(''))
| summarize ['performanceCounters/processPrivateBytes_avg'] = sum(performanceCounter_value)/count() by bin(timestamp,3h)
| order by timestamp desc
| render timechart
```

Comment: Thanks @cijothomas, I am looking for Process Private Bytes. MS naming convention sucks.. :)